# 勉強ばできん - particle ば

Tags: translation, particles, dialects

In Gabaibaachan, in ch. 15, at a climax in the story, the protagonist's mother finally makes an appearance and cheers him on at a running race. He calls back:

> 勉強ばできんばってん足が早かろうが--!

"I'm a terrible student but I'm a good runner, aren't I?"

My question is what the ば particle is doing there. It seems to replace が. Is this a common feature of Sagaben?

Edit:

After reading the comments below, I realise ば can replace を in the 九州 dialect. After googling をできない, I found some examples of this collocation, even though I would have expected　ができない. So, my updated question is, is the character in fact saying, 「勉強(が)をできない」?

Comment: Related?: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46744/9831

Comment: Could be a dialect, or just a specific way that that character speaks (adding random ba's)? Not sure. I know that できんばってん is a Kyushu dialect for できないけど.

Comment: Actually I just found something on ば in the kyushu dialect.   https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1282839512

Comment: The answer says 'ba' replaces 'wo'; but 'ga' seems a better fit, unless the character is saying, 'benkyou wo dekin'. (It's hard for me to write Japanese script on my phone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 勉強**ば**できんばってん足が早かろうが--!
>   *I've a bad brain (or I'm not smart) but I'm a good runner, aren't I?*

In this sentence ば stands for は, a topic marker, in がばいばあちゃん's region in Saga prefecture. It is a common Kyushu dialect.
As for the ば in the following sentence also by がばいばあちゃん written [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46744/why-is-%E3%81%B0-in-this-sentence) stands for を.

> そんなトコで何**ば**しよる。
>   *What are you doing there?*

I don't know why, but ば is flexible in the dialect.

Comment: 辞書やWikipedia、その他ブログなども探したんですが、「ば」は「を＋は」からきていて対格「を」の意味だ、というものしか見つかりません。九州あるいは佐賀のほうで「ば」が「は」か「が」の意味で使われるということが書かれたソースか何かありませんか。

Comment: @Chocolate: がばいばあちゃんの本からの質問とは知らず、「そんなトコで何ばしよる。」の質問に、私は「**が** は **を**」,「九州地方の老女の‌​発言」と回答しましたが全く評価されなかったことを覚えております。現地‌​の言葉を肌で知っている立場で回答します。所望のソースがあるかどうか存じません。 「ば」のありそうな例として、「うちの孫は勉強**ば**できん」（勉強はできない＞勉強ができない）「あの子、今勉強**ば**しちょる」（勉強をしている：現在進行形）です。今考えると、「ばってん」も曲者ですね。Robertさんのいう「が」にすると、「ばってん」がない文では問題なしですが、「勉強**が**できんばってん足が早かろうが」を現地の人が聞くと、「勉強ができないので、足が早（速？）いだろうが」という意味になり、原文とは意味が異なります。単独では「ば」は「は」でも「が」でもよかったですが、「ばってん」という接続詞（？）によって、「が」と翻訳するのは間違いになります。その意味で、原文の「ば」は「は」です。もう一つ別の解釈は「ば」が「をば」です。これですと、「を」と解釈したい人に少し好都合です。またお尋ねください。

Comment: Chocolate: 《つづき》　「勉強ばできんばってん足が速かろうが--!」には本来、つぎのように読点が必要なのだと思います。「勉強ばできん、ばってん足が早（速）かろうが--!」　これだと、今テーマにしている「ば」が、「は」であっても「が」であっても、同じ意味になります。すなわち、「ばってん」が、いずれの解釈でも本来の「しかし but」の意味で理解されます。しかし、読点がない場合に「ば」が意味を持ちます。日本人は意識しておりませんが、英語で日本語を勉強している世界では、「は」のことをtopic marker という便利な呼び名でその働きを明確にしております。たぶんがばいばあちゃんの文にある「ば」はtopic markerと呼んで良いような働きをしているのでしょう。意味的には as forのような意味になるのでしょうか。「は」と解釈すると、「勉強はできない≒勉強についていうならば出来が悪い」と一区切りありますので、読点がなくとも「ばってん」は、その前に読点があるものとして一呼吸間を置いたのちに発音されるものと思われます。《つづく(2)へ》

Comment: Chocolate: 《つづく(2)から》　しかし、「が」と解釈すると、言い回し上の落ち着き具合から「勉強ができんばってん、足が速かろうが」と読まざるを得ず、「ばってん」の置かれている位置的な処理の方法として、本来の「しかし」という意味合いが薄れて、「なので」と解釈され、結果として「勉強ができないので、足が速かろうが」という変な意味に解釈されるのだと思います。結局「ばってん」は文脈で比較的自在に意味を取る不思議な言葉だなと書きながらも思っております。
「そんなトコで何ばしよる」の「ば」もtopic markerのように思っております。普通なら「そんなトコで何しよる」でもよいはずです。「勉強しよる」も普通に使いますが、「勉強ばしよる」は「（遊びとかほかのことではなく）勉強をしている」という意味です。ですから、「そんなトコで何ばしよる」の「ば」は単なる「を」でなく、「一体全体何をしている」というようなニュアンスで使われています。

Comment: 文献・ソースはない（かもしれない）が、mackyさんご自身が九州弁をご存じで、「ば」が "topical は" として使われる例があることをご存じだということですね。

Comment: `「九州地方の老女の‌​発言」と回答しましたが全く評価されなかったことを` ← そのスレッドについては、私自身しっかり読んでいなかったので、質問にもどちらの回答にも投票していないので、何とも言えません