# Meaning of these ば after a noun

Tags: particles, dialects

Watching *Ping Pong: The Animation*, I found several sentences with ば after a name; while I know the conditional ば, I'm not sure what this should mean:

> やつが部屋に張っとうポスターばわしは笑えん。
>
> うちは勝手ん対外試合ばやることば厳しく禁じちょう
>
> きさんが片高の月本とかいうカットば欲しがるんは構わん
>
> ああ？わしらと苦楽ば共にしてきよった佐久間がのう
>
> そげん話聞いて佐久間がどげん思うばしよろうかのう

It seems to replace を, since all sentencence (not sure for the first and last, though; the last maybe as a slangy 思えば?) seems to work the same if I replace ば with を, and 苦楽を共にする is even a set phrase; I tried to find more about this use, but I didn't find anything.

I'm also unsure about the form ばやることば: is it をやることを, with the second を referring to 禁じる?

Should I read it as を? Is it a colloquial or dialectal use?

Comment: What does "gergal" mean?

Comment: A typo due to my native language, I fixed it; thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46744/9831

Comment: It does, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The ば is を in dialect. I think it is generally considered Kyushu-dialect.

> [〜ば](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/dialect/3168/m0u/)  (福岡の方言) の解説 地域 西部・南部
>
> 〜を。

- [苦楽を共にする](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%8B%A6%E6%A5%BD%E3%82%92%E5%85%B1%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#jn-256892) is a set phrase, but it means more or less literally *to be together when things do and don't work well*.
- 対外試合ばやることば厳しく禁じちょう is 対外試合をやることを厳しく禁じている in Tokyo dialect, meaning *strictly prohibiting doing a (non-official) match with players outside (the school)*. So yes to your question.

---

For the last one, I guess it is changed incorrectly. In the manga version, the corresponding phrase is

> そげな話 聞いて、//佐久間がどげん // 感じおろうかのォ

(/ for break in the bubble). There is no ば.

Answer (score 3):

As luck would have it, I wound up helping to build out the ば entry at Wiktionary.  [Here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%B0#Japanese:_object) is the relevant section.

@[sundowner](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/45489/) has the right of it in their [answer post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/98013/5229).

I'd like to add to that post a bit.

#### Where does this ば particle come from?

This was ultimately the same thing as the topic particle は.  This was used, and can still be used, to introduce a contrastive or emphasizing sense.  Compare:

- 店【みせ】に行【い】く → [I] go to the store.
- 店【みせ】に**[は]{●}**行【い】く → It's the store that I go to (as opposed to somewhere else).

Historically, this usage of は could also happen after the object particle を.  This particular combination would cause [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) or "sequential voicing", shifting the は (*wa*) to ば (*ba*).  We first see this usage all the way back in the [*Man'yōshū*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dsh%C5%AB) compilation of poetry, completed in about 759.  *(For more about why* wa *voices to* ba*, see [this other post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82475/why-does-fu-changes-to-pu-while-its-not-started-with-h/82477#82477).)*  Some modern dialects of Japanese still use this をば as an emphatic form of を.

Other modern dialects of Japanese used this をば so much that it replaced just plain を, and due to a phonological (sound) shift, をば shortened or abbreviated to just ば.  The big 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】, similar to the *Oxford English Dictionary* only for Japanese, cites this first to a text in the early 1800s.

References:

- NKD entry for をば: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%92%E3%81%B0-666115
  The *Man'yōshū* quote is right towards the top of the entry.
- NKD entry for ば: https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%B0-597816
  Look for the 〘係助〙 section towards the bottom of the page.